# A pointless question about geometry (or a question about point-free geometry)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Sorry, it seems to be silly-season for me at the moment; I'm reading up on Category Theory (following "Category Theory in Context", by Emily Riehl, which I like), and it inspires a lot of speculation - this time I came across the concept of point-free topology. The idea here is that you take topology spaces, throw away the underlying point-sets and study what is left. So, to the question:

Is there any theory for point-free *differential* geometry?

Apparently not, which may not be surprising, considering the inherent difficulty in talking about differentiation in such a context. But is it impossible? And what would it take? I imagine one would have to dream up some sort of algebraic structure that would work for certain parts of what is intuitively "open subsets" - eg. for a 'topology' $\tau$, there would be an operator $+ \colon \tau \times \tau \rightarrow \tau$, so for some $o_1, o_2 \in \tau$ $\exists o_3 \in \tau \colon o_3 = o_1 + o_2$ - and so on. (sorry for rambling on, but I think it is interesting). Is it crazy?

Comment: You might want to look up synthetic differential geometry. It is essentially differential geometry with a topos-theoretic (hence category-theoretic) approach.

Comment: Also I do not really understand the last part. What exactly should the algebraic structure you are envisioning represent? Are you referring to operations like unions and intersections? If yes, the notion of a [frame](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/frame) more or less axiomatizes the idea.

Comment: Ah, yes synthetic differential geometry, but that's still some way off for me. As for my musings about operators - I'm really just groping around in the dark; my thinking ATM is that point-free geometry would be essentially 'fuzzy', and that one would want to preserve this fuzzyness in whatever 'differential' structure was created. Naively, differentiation involves things like subtraction and division, so perhaps one would need some sort of fuzzy arithmetics? The question is how to marry the fundamental exactness of differentiation with the fuzzyness (and the woollyness of my thinking)?

Comment: If I understand your thoughts correctly, let's take a space within the context of this point-free geometry, and let's say we want a notion of a 'funtion' (real-valued or whatever) on this space. Rather than determining the function by fixing the value at every point, we determine it by fixing a range of values at every 'neighbourhood of points'. Adding two functions becomes 'fuzzy' in the sense that we no longer add fixed values pointwise, but we add ranges of values 'neighbourhood-wise'. That does sound pretty cool.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply - I have been thinking a lot about this, since it is at the heart of the problem, I think, but I'm wary of ranges of values. I suppose, my thinking goes like this: think of a manifold: a topological space, coordinate maps etc; then throw away the point-sets from both ends of the coordinate maps and work out something based on 'coordinate-maps' that go from topology to topology. Synthetic differential geometry would presumably be the language that guides the hand as to which parts are essential (?). But I still can't quite decide the specifics, yet.

Comment: Aha! I had a look at the wikipedia page for synthetic differential geometry and found that one of my old professors from Aarhus University, Anders Kock, appears to be the Big Man in that subject. I should have taken more of an interest; alas for my misspent youth.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I have nothing valuable to add other than that I hope you think about it more and see what you can come up with. Even if you find nothing interesting my personal experience is that exploring on your own is more rewarding (and fun!) than following books. Good luck!

Comment: But you have already added value, I think. You got me to look at synthetic differential geometry, which I had only thought of as something of peripheral interest, and it made me realise that it may well be central.